# difference between \r\n  and  \n\n in php email

Tags: php, email, newline

I'm setting up a php mail sending script...

While adding different headers, I've come across the symbol for a new line in the email (since a < br > tag won't do)...

So my question is what is the difference between \r\n and \n\n ?

for example:

```
echo $var1 . " \r\n" . $var2 . "\n\n";
```

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\r` means carriage return and `\n` means new line.  Its easier to think about it like a type writer, the `\r` is when you push the paper holder (maybe it is called a carriage???) from the left to right, so you can type at the beginning of the line, and the `\n` will lower the line by one.  Traditionally windows and windows based programs required both, but most programs now recognize `\n` as a new line for all operating systems.

Comment: Thanks and great comparison (but i think it's right to left on a typewriter to go to the beginning of a line?).

So \r\n it is....

Also would it matter to do \n\r or probably not?

Comment: I thought that right to left too, but then when I visualized it I realized the paper moves to the left as you type, and it needs to be pushed back to the right when you start a new line, because it is the paper that moves and not the typing point. And I am not sure if \n\r will work, I would guess yes (for things that require \r\n), but I don't have any way to test it right now :p

Comment: haha well that's what I get for being in 'too young' to remember typewriters....thanks for the response!

Answer (score 7):

`\r\n` is the standard.

From [RFC 2822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt)

> Messages are divided into lines of characters.  A line is a series of
>      characters that is **delimited with the two characters carriage-return
>      and line-feed**; that is, the carriage return (CR) character (ASCII
>      value 13) followed immediately by the line feed (LF) character (ASCII
>      value 10).  (The carriage-return/line-feed pair is usually written in
>      this document as "CRLF".)

The other `\n\n` is just 2 lines.

If this is the email headers I believe it would be

```
echo $var1 . " \r\n" . $var2 . "\r\n\r\n";
```

Here `\r\n\r\n` is the delimiter of header and body. It could be HTTP or SMTP

Answer (score 2):

`\r\n` is a new line in windows and `\n\n` would be two new lines on UNIX like systems.

Don't confuse a new line with a line break, which exists in HTML. It's basically just a new line you would see in a plain text file but not in browsers.

See [Newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

Answer (score 2):

Actually \r\n is the windows standard for a single line break. The unix standard is a single \n character.

Mostly (in emails) you can ignore the \r character and only use \n for a single line break. Which also means that \n\n represents a double line break.

Comment: Thanks, so by using \r\n i'm essentially writing a line break in windows AND unix?

Comment: That's correct. But recent email clients (also for windows) also recognize a single \n character as line breaks.

Comment: Be aware that some email servers will reject emails which contain \n instead of \r\n - ideally you need to ensure the code generating the email always outputs \r\n for every end of line. Search "Bare LF SMTP" for more info.

Answer (score 1):

`"\r\n"` is primarily used in DOS, while in UNIX it is express in `"\n"`. So if you interpret `"\n\n"` in UNIX it will be equivalent to two line break. Since you mention PHP, it's safe to use PHP predefined constant `PHP_EOL`.

Answer (score 0):

\n is a new line and \r is a carriage return.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#In_programming_languages

Answer (score 0):

`\r` carriage return moves the input position back to the beginning.  Then `\n` advances to the new line.